# How to control a growing Scheduler Delay under Spark 1.6.2?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm running a streaming job under Spark 1.6.2 which takes batches from a queue. I've tried various sizes of memory and numbers of executors, for example:

```
spark-submit --class "MyStreamingClass" --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 11g --executor-memory 11g
--num-executors 7 --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=256 mystuff-*.jar
```

Each batch requests a re-processing of the same set of data, updating changing values. That is, same structure, same size,
same keys, but the values are updated with each batch. With each request, the amount of time between the request being read from the
queue and being delivered to the input DStream grows. I take this to be the Scheduler Delay. This value is controllable to
some extent by adjusting the memory and number of executors. The problem is that Scheduler Delay grows with each batch,
and can take several minutes after a couple requests. The Long keys never change, so the HashPartitioner uses the same
keys each time. It's a small amount of data, less than 100M, but the processing is extensive and needs to be spread across nodes.

Why would the Scheduler Delay grow so rapidly, especially since the keys don't change? What do I need to change to stabilize the Scheduler Delay?

Comment: is your processing time more than batch interval?

Comment: @NishantKumar - It is longer. Each batch is handled separately, though. I'm submitting a batch, waiting for it to clear, then entering the next. The hope is that the cluster would be in a clean state and process each batch without interference from the previous.

Answer (score 0):

What I've found here is that some of the processing was taking longer than the batch time. In that case the framework could never catch up. The solution is to either reduce the batch time, or make the processing fit into batch time by increased resources or optimization.